# Gray NSTableView à la iTunes

Tags: cocoa

How can I achieve the dark gray `NSTableView` look (used in iTunes, Delicious Library, etc.) in my own application?

[image: iTunes NSTableHeaderView]

I always thought this was an option in `NSTableView` (or `NSTableHeaderView`) but I never tried actually doing it.

After hours of searching, I'm pretty convinced that no such option exists, and that I need to do my own drawing.

Before going any further, I just want to make sure there isn't an (undocumented) API for this, and that I'm not missing something.

Answer (score 2):

A good friend of mine created a whole control kit called [BGHUDAppKit](http://binarymethod.com/). It's for the new HUD stuff that Apple introduced a while ago. I believe his controls are themable, and they come with source. I personally haven't done anything with Cocoa, but he has and I know he could answer some questions. Unfortunately, he doesn't lurk here, so you'll have to contact him. I'll see if I can get him to come here. :)

Answer (score 1):

Look at [this page](http://mattgemmell.com/source) under iTableColumnHeader. Also there are many custom UI elements similar to Apple's